# Creating 5 communication groups in MPI

Tags: c++, mpi

Hello everyone can you please help with creating 5 communication groups, each with 6 processes. This is my code so far...

```
MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    int rank;
    int size;
    
    
    int color = rank / 5;

    int row_rank, row_size;
    MPI_Comm comm;
        MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
        MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
        MPI_Comm_split(MPI_COMM_WORLD, color, rank, &comm);

        MPI_Comm_size(comm, &row_size);
        MPI_Comm_rank(comm, &row_rank);
printf("WORLD RANK AND SIZE: %d / %d \t ROW/ SIZE: %d / %d  \t COMMUNICATOR: %d\n", rank, size, row_rank, row_rank, color);

MPI_Finalize();
}
```

When I try to run the code it always shows zero in the place of the communication

Comment: how many MPI tasks are you running?

Comment: You're printing the color as "COMMUNICATOR". Is that what you want? And if you want 5 groups of 6 processes, you need 30 processes. Is that how you start MPI?

Comment: You want to set `color = rank / 5` AFTER you've set the value of `rank`. Right now you use the unitinialized value of `rank`, which is likely 0 if this is at the start of your program (though this is not guaranteed).